# How to enable viewBinging in android project using Kotlin gradle dsl?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

android {
    ...I'm trying to enalbe **ViewBinding** in my project witch use Kotlin Gradle DSL.
All examples show how to do it with Groovy DSL.

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

But this solution isn't works with Kotlin DSL.
I was trying solution like this:

```
android {
    ...
    viewBinding.enabled = true
}
```

But it also doesn't work. It's interesting, that this approach works for DataBinding.

Answer (score 1):

Just an updated way of doing same thing, since ***isEnabled*** is *deprecated*.

just add this block

```
 viewBinding {
    android.buildFeatures.viewBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of old android gradle plugin version.
After updating up to 3.6.2 version the problem was solved.